# Unable to load hierachical data in Grid. 0 items

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I keep getting "No items to display" in my child grids.
I have 2 view models,  Master and Name. A Master can have multiple Names bound.
When I execute the page, it shows me Master information as expected. But its child, Name, has no items displayed although when I breakpoint on the JSON it contains 2 Names that it is returning.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@(
 Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("MainGrid")
    .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Bound(m => m.ListingId).Width(100);
        col.Bound(m => m.Gender).Width(100);

    })
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("NameGridTemplate")
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .Model(m => m.Id(i => i.ListingId))
        .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Master", "Main"))  
    )
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))

)

<script id="NameGridTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<NameViewModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=ListingId#") // template expression, to be evaluated in the master context
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.PersonName).Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Type).Width(110);

            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Name", "Main", new { listingId = "#=ListingId#" }))

            )
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>

<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }
</script>
```

**Master ViewModal**
     public class MasterViewModal
    {

```
    public int ListingId { get; set; }

    public String Gender { get; set; }

    public int? Swn { get; set; }

    public DateTime? SwnExpDate { get; set; }

    public String Source { get; set; }

    public Boolean PrStatus { get; set; }

    public String PrCountry { get; set; }

    public Boolean PermanentBan { get; set; }

    public String BanIssueAgency { get; set; }
}
```

**NameViewModal**
    public class NameViewModel
    {
        public int ListingId { get; set; }
        public String PersonName { get; set; }
        public String Type { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateLastUpd { get; private set; }
        public String UserLastUpd { get; private set; }
    }

**Main controller**
     public class MainController : Controller
        {

```
        ListingContext db = new ListingContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Master> dataList = null;

            dataList = db.Masters.ToList();
            List<MasterViewModal> mvmList = Logic.GetMasterViewModels(dataList);
            return View(mvmList);
        }

        public ActionResult HierarchyBinding_Master([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            List<Master> masterList = null;
            masterList = db.Masters.ToList();
            return Json(Logic.GetMasterViewModels(masterList));
        }

        public ActionResult HierarchyBinding_Name(int listingId, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            List<Name> nameList = null;
            nameList = db.Names.ToList();
            JsonResult j = Json(nameList
                .Where(name => name.ListingId == listingId)
                .ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return j;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
public ActionResult HierarchyBinding_Name(int listingId, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    List<Name> nameList = null;
    nameList = db.Names.ToList();

    return  Json(nameList
        .Where(name => name.ListingId == listingId)
        .ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Remove the Jsonrequestbehaviour.Allowget.

I think it ll work. I dont see anything wrong with your razor code